# killing kube pod on the fly with python

Tags: python, kubernetes, devops

I have code/app running on Kubernetes.
and I want a way to dynamically(from the code) kill the pod.
does someone know a way do to it, I tried to exit the process and raise error but it didn't work

Comment: I would also be curious about why you want to do this? Kubernetes by nature self recovers, so if you're trying to delete a pod, Kubernetes will just spin it back up again? Could we have some background context?

Comment: i have a memory leak on my app, the app is fetching from SQS a msg and work on it, but between msg the memory don't get clean up. finding the problem is gonna take me a lot of time, so i though as patch : why i don't check my memory between msg and if i'm over 70% of the dedicated memory kill the pod and the autoscalle would restart it whit empty memory

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to my comment above, I understand your app has a memory leak and you want to restart the pod to clean up that memory leak.

First, I will state the obvious and the best way to fix the problem is to the fix the leak in the code. That being said, you have also said finding the problem will take a lot of time.

The other solution I can think of is to utilise Kubernete's own resource requests/limits functionality.

You declare how much memory and/or CPU you want the node to reserve for your app and you can also declare how much memory and/or CPU you want the node to give your app at max. If the CPU usage exceeds the limit declared, the app is throttled. If the memory usage exceeds the limit declared, it becomes `OOMKilled`

Keeping the memory limit low will allow your app to be restarted if it exceeds the memory limit you declared.

Details of this, and a examples (which includes a memory leak example) can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/